# Launch CoreData View Not From AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I am playing about with Core Data and very new to it. This chunk of code seems pretty important:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

It sets the `managedObjectContext` to the desired view right? (This time being `MasterViewController`

Now I have played with it but can't seem to get it working. What if I want to launch the `MasterViewController` from somewhere else in the app, not directly from/as the root view?

### Edit

My views as seen in InterFace Builder:

`UINavigationController` >Relationship> `UIViewController` >Push Segue> `UITableViewController`

So in Interface builder, the UINavigationBar is the blank, first controller and then UIViewController is connected to that and is the first view the user will see in the app. Then I want to get from there to my UITableViewController where I have my CoreData usage.

Comment: What is not working? The core data template should be working fine.

Comment: I am not actually using the template, although the code in my project is essentially identical as the template. What I want to do is instead of loading the tableview as the top/rootview controller I want to launch it from another place, say get to it from another one of my own views. However it won't directly, I can't simply move the Interface Builder connection from the nab controller to another one of my views, theatre is something in the code which I can't figure out. The code I mention in the question is the code which I believe is to do with this.

Comment: No, it's not. Just follow the checklist I posted as an answer.

Comment: Hi Josh, did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions :
You have to passed your `NSManagedObjectContext` throught all your app between all your UIViewController

or

Get your `NSManagedObjectContext` from anywhere like that :

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] mainManagedObjectContext];
```

Comment: I've tried the second method, putting that in the `viewDidLoad` of the viewI want to use core data within but no such luck. Granted its likely I need to change some things, but I am basing my tableviewcontroller off one you see in a fresh project as well, so it shares the same code allowing core data to be used to add timestamps. Because of this I am getting this following error when not going to the tableview directly from the root: UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: A better way of putting this possibly would be to say that the code in my project replicates that of if anyone was to make a new project with core data. The only thing is, if you look at the storyboard, I want to whack a view or two of my own between the nab controller and the tableviewcontroller. So I am loading the view not from the root but from my own view somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that :

1. Your view controller (not view) has access to the right `managedObjectContext`.
2. Your table view `datasource` gets its data from `self.fetchedResultsController`.
3. You configure your fetched results controller to fetch the correct data for your tableview.

Comment: Im almost positive that 2 and 3 are good. The generated code in the template handles that. Not sure about 1 though. keeping all code as the template, only changing the Interface Builder segue so that I get my tableview controller from my own view and not the root view, I get this error: '-[ViewController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f730'. `ViewController` is my view which I want to get to the tableviewcontroller from (its not the root view).

Comment: More explanation: `ViewController` is my view which connects to the root view. So I have the root nab controller which connects to this `ViewController` (the first view of the app) which then I want to connect to my tableviewcontroller.

Comment: It seems there is some confusion about view and controllers. You should have your `UIViewController` **contain** a `UITableView`. You can also take a `UITableViewController` which will already have a table view set up for you. -- Then you connect the `datasource` of the `UITableView` to your core data via `UIFetchedResultsController`. - Clear?

Comment: Hmm I thought I understood but practically not working. Check my edit please, a better explanation of how I have my views/controllers.